# Can't drag object into script field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't drag my object from the photo I want to fade in/out into this field, but I'm sure I put this script in the canvas.
Already tried everything in my opinion, but nothing comes out.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Fade : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup canvasgroup;

    private bool _fadein = false;
    private bool _fadeout = false;

    public float TimeToFade;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(_fadein){
            if(canvasgroup.alpha < 1){
                canvasgroup.alpha += TimeToFade * Time.deltaTime;
                if(canvasgroup.alpha >= 1){
                    _fadein=false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(_fadeout){
            if(canvasgroup.alpha >= 0){
                canvasgroup.alpha -= TimeToFade * Time.deltaTime;
                if(canvasgroup.alpha == 0){
                    _fadeout=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void FadeIn()
    {
        _fadein = true;
    }

    public void FadeOut()
    {
        _fadein = false;
    }
}
```

================

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ensure the object you want to fade in/out has the [CanvasGroup component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasGroup.html).

[image: CanvasGroup component]